# c++ vector erase advances iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, erase

The following simplified code works, in that it deletes all vector elements. However, I do not understand why. Since `f.erase(r)` does not capture the returned value which would be the new iterator value, and there is no other iterator incrementor, and [according to documentation,](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)  `erase(iterator position)` argument is not passed by reference, where does the iterator get advanced?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> f = {1,2,3,4,5};
  auto r = f.begin();
  while (r != f.end())
  {
    std::cout << "Erasing " << *r << std::endl;
    f.erase(r);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land where the result you want can even be the result you get.  If you want to empty a vector, just use `clear()` -> `f.clear();`

Comment: `erase` invalidates iterators, so you shall not use `r` after that. "it works" is the worst incarnation of undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where does the iterator get advanced?

It doesn't, the iterator stays pointing to the same location.  This is technically undefined behavior but if you think about what the loop is actually doing, you'll see why you get the "correct" results.

Your vector holds a pointer to the objects that it stores.  Your iterator is going to point to that memory with the offset to the element you want.  In this case it is going to point to the beginning of the data.  When you erase the first element, the iterator is invalidated but it is still pointing to the beginning of the vector.  `erase` moves all of the elements forward so when you go into the next iteration, your in the same state that you were in the first iteration except the vector is one element smaller.  You repeatedly do this until there are no elements left and `end() == begin()`

You should not depend on this always happening though and instead just use `clear()` to remove all of the elements from the vector.

Answer (score 2):

> where does the iterator get advanced?

The iterator does not get advanced. The fact that your code seems to work is just by chance and in fact you have undefined behaviour.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) on `std::vector::erase`:

> Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

You are not allowed to use `r` after calling `f.erase(r);`. If you do, funny things can happen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write

```
  while (r != f.end())
  {
    std::cout << "Erasing " << *r << std::endl;
    r = f.erase(r);
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
```

because after erasing the iterator becomes invalid.

Or you could just write

```
f.clear();
```

because the loop removes all elements of the vector.

Take into account that as the iterator r is used only in the loop it is better to declare it in the scope of the loop that is where it is used. for example

```
  for ( auto r = f.begin(); r != f.end(); )
  {
    std::cout << "Erasing " << *r << std::endl;
    r = f.erase(r);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding/removing elements to/from vector in most cases (that includes erase())invalidates references and iterators. Using old iterators results in undefined behavior.

As @Nathan mentioned in the comments `f.clear()` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

> and [according to documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/),

You should read it to the end:

[vector::erase - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, erasing elements in positions other than the [vector end](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector::end) **causes the container to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions**. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence containers (such as [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/list) or [forward_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/forward_list)).

and

> #### Return value
>
> An iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call. This is the [container end](http://www.cplusplus.com/vector::end) if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.

[vector::erase - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

And finally:

> #### Iterator validity
>
> Iterators, pointers and references pointing to *position* (or *first*) and beyond are invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before *position* (or *first*) are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.

Answer (score 0):

`erase` invalidates `r`. Dereferening `r` after that causes undefined behavior.

---

But in the real world, it shouldn't cause any problems unless the implementation intentionally checks iterator validity.

A `vector` iterator normally only stores a pointer to the element. When you delete an element, all elements to the right of it are shifted to the left by one position. Because of that, the memory location that used to be occupied by the deleted element, will be occupied by the next element.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is explaining UB considered heresy now? :P

Comment: Didn't downvote, but _"it shouldn't cause any problems"_ is... Just no. And not just because of false positives in checked builds.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I can't think of any other reason why it could break things.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the iterator to `erase` invalidates that iterator, and therefore using it further (when passing it to `erase` in the next iteration) has undefined behaviour. Thus, the program doesn't actually "work". It may appear to work, because that is one possible behaviour. But that behaviour is not guaranteed.